# Android billing - how do I invoke the onUpgradeAppButtonClicked() method if it is not from a button click?

Tags: android, android-billing

I am creating the subscription purchase for an app. And I originally had something like this:

```
    // CREATE THE SUBSCRIBE BUTTON
    Button subscribe = (Button)findViewById(R.id.subscribe);
    subscribe.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() 
    {  
      public void onClick(View v) 
      {             
          onUpgradeAppButtonClicked ( );
      }
    });                   

public void onUpgradeAppButtonClicked( ) 
{
    Log.d(TAG, "Buy button clicked; launching purchase flow for upgrade.");
    setWaitScreen(true);
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, SKU_SUBSCRIPTION, RC_REQUEST, mPurchaseFinishedListener);
}
```

But then I read that the IABHelper needs to get set asynchronously. And that invoking this method from a button click might not be right.

But how does it possibly get invoked if not from a button click?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose what was meant is, that it will take some time, so you should run it asynchronously, so it does not freeze your UI. So, sure you'll invoke it from a button click, but not directly. Instead, in your `onUpgradeAppButtonClicked()` method, do something to run the `mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow()...` asynchronously, like using an `AsyncTask` or a separate `Thread` or the like.

The famous [Painless Threading Article](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.at/2009/05/painless-threading.html) comes, as always, very handy for this.

Comment: thanks - but that is what I am currently doing....I think.  Does that mean I am all set? :) Also, if they need to unsubscribe, should I just launch the same method?

Comment: Yes, I think you're all set then. As for unsubscribing I don't know, as I've never implemented in app billing myself. But basically I'd say, if it works, it's fine.